# Problems loading pgAudit library on Postgres 12.2

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to add the pgAudit extension to register the events of my database. I downloaded pgAudit and installed via git.

```
git clone https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit.git
cd pgaudit
git checkout REL_11_STABLE
gmake install USE_PGXS=1
```

And added `'pgaudit'` to the `shared_preload_libraries`. However, when I try to start the server, it throws the following error:

```
FATAL: could not load library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/pgaudit.so": /usr/local/lib/postgresql/pgaudit.so: Undefined symbol "IsSystemNamespace".
```

I've googled for a while but cannot find what's wrong. I've checked that the library is really there and uninstalled/reinstalled it. I'm currently working with FreeBSD-12.0 RELEASE and PostgreSQL 12.12.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This commit](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=2d7d946cd323ce1c1d3f3ef0e5f2f41591afc1b9) renamed `IsSystemNamespace` to `IsCatalogNamespace` in PostgreSQL v12, so you must have built the extension with PostgreSQL v11 or older by mistake.

Check the result of

```
which pg_config
```

to see what was first on your `PATH` when you built the extension.

Be explicit with

```
make USE_PGXS=1 PG_CONFIG=/path/to/pg12/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 1):

You did `git checkout REL_11_STABLE` according to `README.md` but that  branch is just an example chosen when PostgreSQL 11 was the latest version.

In the case of PostgreSQL 12, the branch you should choose is `REL_12_STABLE`.

`git remote show origin` can be issued to show the available branches:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    REL9_5_STABLE tracked
    REL9_6_STABLE tracked
    REL_10_STABLE tracked
    REL_11_STABLE tracked
    REL_12_STABLE tracked
    dev-stack     tracked
    master        tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

---

This way of making the user select a specific branch is unusual. In general, extensions have a common branch for all versions of PostgreSQL, and `pg_config` is used by the build to know which version is the target. When there are several versions of PostgreSQL installed, the build invoker should take care of using specifically the `pg_config` of the desired version, as shown in [Laurenz Albe's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/271121/7119).